# Can the IIS version be specified in a web.config so as to avoid e.g. "the useKernalMode attribute is not allowed"?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, iis, web-config

The following shows a section from the web.config file for an application we're running in IIS. I've included it as an image so as to include the green line under `useKernelMode`, and the error message shown when hovering over it.

(*Note: As you can see, this also applies to `UseAppPoolCredentials` and `extendedProtection`. I just selected `useKernelMode` for this example*)

[image]

The configuration here should be correct - it was set up by an admin who presumably knows what he is doing, and it does seem to work fine. There is also [documentation for Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/) which identifies `useKernelMode` as a valid attribute.

Why then is this marked as an invalid attribute? Different versions of IIS obviously support different elements and attributes in config files - could it be that Visual Studio somehow relates this config file to an older standard for web.confi files, in which the attribute was in fact not valid? If so, is there some way for me to specify that this particular config should be validated according to a specific version of IIS, e.g. IIS 7.5, 8.5, or 10?

After all, I *would* like any real mistakes in my web.config to be marked this way, but I'd like to avoid (presumably) false positives like this.

Comment: Technically that’s difficult to implement by VS, as there are indeed various versions of IIS out there today and they have different schemas. Even IIS 10 has several variations. You can raise a feature request to Microsoft but I don’t expect them to deliver it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid it has nothing to do with IIS version. IIS locked it up and set to read only.

[image]

As you can see, the section is only allowed by applicationhost.config level.

[image]

If you access this in visual studio, you will receive
[image]

If you want to fix  this, plesae set applicationhost.config.

```
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

to

```
<section name="windowsAuthentication" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

After that, VS still report invaild attribute but IIS express and IIS will allow these attributes in web.config

[image]

[image]